# Why was Lord Vader crying?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, revenge-of-the-sith

Darth Vader cries in the scene right after he kills the separatist leaders.

[image]

Why does he cry? Remorse for killing the separatist leaders who were manipulated and discarded by Palpatine? Remorse for killing Jedi master Mace Windu, younglings, and the other Jedi?  Grief over what he has become? Sadness over some vision of his future?

I am looking for an in-universe answer supported by at least G-canon. Is this covered in a novelization?

There is a clear out-of-universe reason: Lucas wants the audience to know that Vader has **not** become all twisted and evil, more machine than man, as Kenobi described in *The Return of the Jedi*.

Comment: Give the guy a break. He just had a terrible, horrible, messed up, no-good day.

Comment: his humanity seeping out ?

Comment: No cannon answer available, personal theory is that he realized he became what the woman he loves hates most...a viscous dictator.

Comment: NoooooooooooooooooooOOooooo!!!!

Comment: There's nothing in the script or novelisations that explain it directly

Comment: There's nothing worse than a thick, sticky dictator.

Comment: Anakin is clearly being affected by the Dark Side at this point (see his eyes at the end of the clip, since normal human eyes don't just spontaneously turn orange), and we know the Dark Side can affect also your mental state. He's quite possibly being overwhelmed by Dark Side related feelings (fear, anger, loss, suffering, etc). Extreme anger, for example, can cause crying.

Answer (score 2):

### George Lucas, ROTS DVD Commentary:

> **"Anakin's on the balcony contemplating what he’s done. This is the first time he actually has a chance to think about what it is that’s
> happened by himself and the tear here shows that he knows what he’s
> done but he’s not committed himself a path that he may not agree with
> but he is going to go along anyway.**
>
> It’s the one moment that says he’s self aware. He rationalizing all
> his behavior. He’s doing terrible things. But in the end he really
> knows the truth. He knows that he’s evil now and there’s nothing he
> can do about it and that’s the moment where the pathos of him being
> stuck in that suit is real because if he had to do it over he probably
> wouldn’t do it but he can't stop it now.
>
> You know where it's going to lead. He knows it will end with a fight
> with Obi-Wan. He knows that Padme not buy into this new reality. He
> made a pact with the devil and now he’s become the devil."

https://www.head-fi.org/threads/star-wars-episodes-i-vi.141501/page-3